# How to make this PHP code pass the php-cs-fixer?

Tags: php-cs-fixer

Php-cs-fixer returns the error 'braces' for one of the files. The following code causes the problem:

```
$meetings = Meeting::where(function ($query) use ($meeting_type_id) {
    //doSomething
});
```

Php-cs-fixer uses the default psr1, psr2 rules (vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --verbose --format=txt).

How do i make this code pass the php-cs-fixer?

Comment: not sure on the code styles, maybe the `function(` or put `{` on a new line

Comment: Is there a more descriptive error message than "braces"?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Just do a backup of your file, run php-cs-fixer without the --dry-run, and compare the fixed file with the backup. Doing this just added a new line after the semicolon, which fixed the issue.

Comment: I wished that worked for me. I removed the --dry-run, it showed fixed in the log. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by assigning the function to a variable and use this as an argument. Idkw.

```
$queryFunction = function ($query) use ($meeting_type_id) {
        //doSomething
};

$meetings = Meeting::where($queryFunction);
```